# Get raw id token with msal.js (msal-react)

Tags: msal.js

I need to read the raw ID token from a login using msal.js ([@azure/msal-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react)). Authentication works fine and I'm able to read the account using `getAllAccounts()`. But I cannot seem to find any way to extract the raw ID token.

I need to pass the token to a REST API in order to verify the user. I don't want to use access tokens at this point. Is there some way to get the raw ID token? I can see it in localStorage, but I'd rather not grab it directly from there as I suspect that is not supported behavior.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We, too, have one specific situation where we can't use an access token and the problem would be trivial if we could just re-transmit the ID token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy figured it out: https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Microsoft-Authentication-with-MSAL.js

The **idToken** property of the object returned by the MSAL authentication calls (such as **loginPopup**) is the raw JWT.

Example:

```js
PublicClientApplicationInstance.loginPopup(loginRequestConfig).
    then(response => console.log(response.idToken))
```

Comment: Hi @DonR, I noticed you can use the response from awaited `acquireTokenSilent().idToken` . I was hoping there was a way to query the MSAL instance and retrieve it so that I did not have to keep track of it myself in case it was renewed at some point. I guess this is the best current workaround though so I'll mark it as the answer. Appreciate your reply!